# How to scroll to element in v-if with VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, js-scrollto

In my Vue 3 project, I have this button in a component:

```html
<template>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" :data-id="product.id"
    v-on:click="hideButtonAndScroll(product.id)">Get Offer</button>

  <!-- ... some code here ... -->

  <offer-form :product="product"></offer-form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['products'],
  data() {
    return { visibleFormId: 0 };
  },
  methods: {
    hideButtonAndScroll(id) {
      this.visibleFormId = id;
      window.scrollTo({
        top: document.getElementById('product-id-' + id).offsetTop,
        left: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

In the `OfferForm.vue` file, I have this HTML code:

```html
<template>
  <div :id="'product-id-' + product.id">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</template>
```

The problem is when I call the `document.getElementById('product-id-' + id)` function, actually the element doesn't exist yet.

Is there any way to wait until the rendering has finished? and then start scrolling?

Comment: Emit events from OfferForm.vue when data has been loaded and listen to it on parent vue upon which scrolling will be performed.

Answer (score 3):

You can wait until the next render cycle with [`await this.$nextTick()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick) to see any side effects from changing `visibleFormId` (using [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) below):

```js
export default {
  methods: {
  async hideButtonAndScroll(id) {
      this.visibleFormId = id;

    await this.$nextTick();

      window.scrollTo({
        top: document.getElementById('product-id-' + id).offsetTop,
        left: 0,
        behavior: "smooth",
      });
    },
  },
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/query-document-for-conditionally-rendered-element-o5599?file=/src/components/Products.vue)